# Perform Command For List of commands without using IF Statement C#

Tags: c#, .net, command

I have a `TcpListener` Listening on a `NetworkStream` to perform a command examples. "Copy, Move, Delete, ...."

```
switch(command)
{
   case "copy":
   // do copy
   break;
   case "delete":
   // do delete
   break;
   case "move":
   // do move
   break;
   .......................................
}
```

i have implemented it using `switch - case` and `if` statement but when it comes to maintenance or adding a new command, specially when the commands list goes beyond **100 commands** it becomes very hard and tedious, so is there a way to do this efficiently, i have tried searching on **Google** but i can't seem to get the jargon of it correctly
Any help :) **Yaser**

Comment: Have you considered using a dictionary<string, delegate>?

Comment: @ZoharPeled can you please Elaborate more or give me an example

Comment: @GrantWinney i have created separated methods but i want a more efficient way, a more professional way than `if else`

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). You'll have to create an interface `ICommand` and implementation of that interface one per command.

For example: `CopyCommand`, `DeleteCommand`, `MoveCommand` etc.

Then you need a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) which creates instance of respective `ICommand` based on the string provided.

Finally you'll call `ICommand.Execute`. That makes it readable, maintainable, clean and so on..

Your code will become

```
ICommand command = commandFactory.Create(commandString);
command.Execute();
```

Where `commandFactory` is an instance of "Factory" which will create instance of appropriate `ICommand`.

Your Factory class could be implemented using a huge switch case or `Dictionary<string, Func<ICommand>>` if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

As `@Zohar Peled` has already mentioned Dictionary is a really cheap solution for this problem, not so elegant, but really cheap:

```
        //Initialize command lists
        Dictionary<string, Action> commands = new Dictionary<string, Action>();

        commands.Add("move", DoMyMove);
        commands.Add("add", ()=> Console.WriteLine(""));
        commands.Add("remove", DoMyRemove);
        commands.Add("close", DoMyClose);
```

delegate

```
        private void DoMyMove()
        {
             // TODO
        }
```

Usage:

```
        commands[command].Invoke();
```

It's extendable easly and clear for *basic* developers...

Comment: I'm giving you -1 for stealing my idea :-) , but +1 for writing the code example and another +1 for giving credit where credit is due. :-)

Comment: You r  gentle and sry... :(

Answer (score 1):

One option is to define a `Dictionary<string,action>` on the class level that will hold the name of the command and an action delegate to the actual method that needs to be performed. Then in your main method you don't need to use a switch, simply get the [action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate from the dictionary using the dictionary's [`TryGetValue` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and if it returns true simply invoke the action delegate.