# Use an Enum for a Console Command Library (With Implementations)

Tags: c#, command-line, console, command, command-line-arguments

I have researched on Youtube this but nothing has come up, also on Google.
Could anyone please show how use an enum for a Console Command Library, or a better way to process commands.
Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: See [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), forget about enum.

Comment: So you cannot have the console search for the command itself? Must it be in a if,else if,else if tree?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: The program cannot parse the input, then lookup to see if it know what the command is, then use the function according to it? Without the use of a long if statement

Comment: No. You need a if-else ladder, or switch statement or some kind of dictionary mapping. Refer my related [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30105055/2530848) for almost related question. Answer is same;Use command pattern with factory pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing console commands is difficult to do well, and it is a common problem that has been solved many times.  Look for a library to do this for you, or at least to provide some examples.

If you want to parse commands being entered into your program (ie if you are writing a shell of some kind) GNU Readline is an option with available source code (though it is in C).  Information here: http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/rlman_1.html

See this post for C# alternatives for Readline:
[Is there a .Net library similar to GNU readline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024170/is-there-a-net-library-similar-to-gnu-readline)

If you are parsing stuff that was passed to your program as command line options, one option would be getopt: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html

This post talks about C# alternatives to getopt:
[GetOpt library for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172443/getopt-library-for-c-sharp)

Comment: I would prefer to do it myself, but thanks for the answer anyway. Without using a third party library.

Comment: Totally understood, especially if your goal is to learn something new.  In that case, I second the suggestion made by @ Sriram Sakthivel -- google the "Command Pattern" for a general look at one relatively modern way to approach this sort of problem.